# No proper formatting in React App.js in VS Code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, prettier, code-formatting

Working on React got this improper formatting of code

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

as saved this code ctrlS it become distorted difficult to read using VS code

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
    return ( <
        div className = "App" >
        <
        header className = "App-header" >
        <
        img src = { logo }
        className = "App-logo"
        alt = "logo" / >
        <
        p >
        Edit < code > src / App.js < /code> and save to reload. <
        /p> <
        a className = "App-link"
        href = "https://reactjs.org"
        target = "_blank"
        rel = "noopener noreferrer" >
        Learn React <
        /a> <
        /header> <
        /div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

I am facing diffculty to read this code or understand it

I installed Prettier for better formatting but it did not wor at all

Answer (score 0):

Open your setting in vs code.Go to text editor and then to code action On Save.Paste the code in setting.json

```
{
  "editor.defaultFormatter": null,
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
  //   "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
  // },
  "typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "relative",
  "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "[typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
  },
  "[dart]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "editor.rulers": [
      80
    ],
    "editor.selectionHighlight": false,
    "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "editor.tabCompletion": "onlySnippets",
    "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false
  },
  
  
  },
  "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false
}
```